# Joining attributes by the biggest overlapping areas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I have two layers and I want to join the attribute of them together in QGIS. Unfortunately, the overlapping layer (The Blue one) is not very precise, so there are parts that overlap on small areas.

[image]

If I join the attributes together (-> join type: intersects/one to many), I get multiple overlapping attributes. But i only want the attributes with the biggest overlapping area, which would be those:

[image]

If join the attributes together with the one to one method, I often get the attribute of the small overlapping parts, which i don't need/are wrong. I know I can get the mean attributes of all overlapping areas with the "Join Attributes by Location (summary)" function, which is partly a solution to my problem.

But what I really want is to only join the attribute with the biggest overlapping area. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You could run an `intersect`, calculate `$area` for this intersect, then `join attributes by location` the intersect to your original yellowish layer and finally `select by attribute` the geometry with the largest joined area for each geometry with an identical ID (provided, you have IDs on your yellowish layer in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS there is a plugin called ["Select Within"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SelectWithin/).

But building on that I developed my own model to join based on the layer centroids by converting the layer to centroids and then join that table... Works a treat.

Answer (score 13):

Since QGIS 3.12 (see [the Changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#feature-new-mode-to-join-attributes-by-location-to-take-attributes-from-matching-feature-with-largest-area-of-overlap-only) for more details) the ["Join Attributes by Location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) algorithm from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) has a switch to do exactly this:

[image]

> The type of the final joined layer. One of:
>
> ```
> 0 — Create separate feature for each matching feature (one-to-many)
>
> 1 — Take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)
>
> 2 — Take attributes of the feature with largest overlap only (one-to-one)
> ```

Comment: Is it new ? I had a similar problem and I'm pretty sure QGIS wasn't any help.. I wrote a python script with geopandas (so I can make use of multiprocessing)

Comment: I think it was introduced in 3.12