# Assigning attribute by location for multiple layers

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, overlay

I am trying to assign values by location of one of my polygon layer.

It is overlayed by multiple polygon layers and I want to assign the value of the layer that covers it the most.

Is there a tool or a way you can think of in QGIS?

[image]

To make it more clear, I have data as single lines and created buffers of the lines and then areas. The buffers overlap with the areas and I want to assign the yellow (garden) attribute to the areas mostly covered by that, also the same for other values.

So in the example in the image above the area marked with G will get the yellow value as it is mostly covered by that layer and not the pink one.

Comment: Is this about the coverage of the whole layer, or is this about each individual polygon?

Comment: Each individual polygon.
I will add an image to my post now!

Comment: In QGIS 3.12 you can join attributes by the biggest overlapping area (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368414/162856) ! It may work for your example !

Comment: What have you tried ? What are your ideas?

Comment: that's great! I will test this now!

Comment: It worked quite well thank you!